# Why does pandas string series return NaN for len() function?

Tags: python, string, pandas

I am working with a power consumption dataset in Pandas that includes ZIP codes as a column, but the datatype for this column is an integer in the original CSV file. I'd like to change this column to a string/object datatype, and here's what I've done so far:

```
df = pd.read_csv('...kWh_consumption_by_ZIP.csv')
df.head()
```

The resulting dataframe head looks like this:

[image]

As mentioned above, when I check `df.dtypes`, I see that ZIP is listed as *int64* data type, so I run the following code to overwrite the existing series and change it to an *object* data type:

```
df['ZIP'] = df.ZIP.astype(object)
```

Everything looks good when I check the `df.ZIP` series (at least, it looks good to the naked eye):

[image: Screenshot2]

But when I check the length of each row in the series using the len function:

```
df.ZIP.str.len()
```

...the resulting series just returns NaN for each row (see screenshot below).

[image]

Does anyone know why this is this happening? Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: `df.ZIP.astype(str).str.len()`

Comment: So I need to cast the ZIP series as str and not object? I thought object and string were the same thing?

Comment: @Will please see my answer for the "Why".

Comment: @Will you can check cold's answer

Comment: Got it. Thanks, @Wen.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### TL;DR

You have a column of integers, and casting to object has not solved your problem. Instead, typecast to `str` and you should be good.

```
df.ZIP.astype(str).str.len()
```

---

For some reason, pandas supports the `str` accessor on `object` columns. Because `object` columns can contain any object, and pandas makes no assumptions. If the object is a string or any valid container, a valid result is returned. Otherwise, `NaN`.

Here's an example:

```
x = [{'a': 1}, 'abcde', None, 123, 45, [1, 2, 3, 4]]
y = pd.Series(x)

y

0        {'a': 1}
1           abcde
2            None
3             123
4              45
5    [1, 2, 3, 4]
dtype: object

y.str.len()
Out[741]: 
0    1.0
1    5.0
2    NaN
3    NaN
4    NaN
5    4.0
dtype: float64
```

Contrast with:

```
y = pd.Series([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
y

0    1
1    2
2    3
3    4
4    5
dtype: int64

y.dtype
dtype('int64')

y.str.len()
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-744-acc1c109a4a4> in <module>()
----> 1 y.str.len()

y.astype(object).str.len()

0   NaN
1   NaN
2   NaN
3   NaN
4   NaN
dtype: float64
```

Comment: A flower on your head, @Coldspeed.

Comment: This is amazing, just marked a duplicate using this :)

Comment: @Vaishali happy to help :)